# Compile/Open Eclipse bundled plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar

I have downloaded Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and I would like to make some changes to it.

As I can see its plugin folder contains the sources for plugins, for example: `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source_3.103.0.v20120530-1824.jar`

I have found what I would like to change in java files, but I do not know how to open that jar file as an Eclipse project.

I have already tried to check out the plugin from `dev.eclipse.org` CVS repo, but after exporting it as a jar file, Eclipse did not start.

So could you tell me please what is the exact procedure to import/open Eclipse built-in plugins, compile them, then just overwrite the existing jar files wit them?

Answer (score 0):

You have just import `existing project` into workspace. In the import dialog choose `from archived file`.

The suggested way to installing plug-ins is to use `update site`. Then you should create/import `feature project` and `update site project`. But this is not necessary you can put the jar into `plugins` folder.

Note, when you run as eclipse project in the workbench the new workbench is created with already installed project plugin.

However, this jar file serve different purposes to be attached to the library binary jars as source jar.

Comment: Could you tell me please how to open let's say eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source_3.103.0.v20120530-1824.jar as a project?

Comment: Ah, there's no `.project` file in the archive. Then you should create a new project and extract jar to it.

Comment: The best way is checkout project from the eclipse source repository.

Comment: I've checked out the whole eclipse platform, but it is full of errors. Does it require any special setting? (... cannot be resolved)

Comment: You should checkout only version that is corresponding to your eclipse version. Or consider option to build eclipse from sources.